# MSBuild could not copy files to output folder because of unnecessarily many folders

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, msbuild

I'm new to stackoverflow, so if this is a duplicate of a previou question, please redirect me

I'm using a jenkins server to check a local git repo automatically. In this repo there is a testwebsite, written in c# and angular, and jenkins job is to check the git, pull/clone the repo and build a docker image out of that.

But in fact that
[jenkins show me a "success"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKgoP.png), the log throws warnings with many "out" folders. MSBuild can not release the web page and i can not find the fault

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.203/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(141,5): warning MSB3026: Could not copy "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test_master/dockerhosting/out/out/out/out/out/out/out/web.config" to "out/out/out/out/out/out/out/out/web.config". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. The process cannot access the file '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test_master/dockerhosting/out/out/out/out/out/out/out/out/web.config' because it is being used by another process.  [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test_master/dockerhosting/dockerhosting.csproj]
```

The process cannot access the file because of the many out folders. Can anyone here help me out?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you shouldn't have so many nested folders with the same name.
Second, it's failing not because there are too many folders, but because a file `web.config is being used by another process`.

Comment: It's best to just restart your computer and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's right. But i solved this issue and saw that the problem is by jenkins itself. I deleted the multibranch pipe and created a new with the same informations to scan git and build the image. For now, the problem didn't come back. There were some other problems, but they were fixed quickly. Thank you anyway